# Aegir-up (Aegir+Vagrant+Drush) setup

Tags: drupal, vagrant, drush

I am trying to establish a proper Drupal development environment by using [Aegir-up](http://drupal.org/project/aegir-up) (Vagrant-based Aegir virtual machine). I will illustrate how I follow the following "Quick start" steps and fail:

Install dependencies, including drush-vagrant and drush-hosts:

```
    C:\Users\Domas>drush dl drush-vagrant drush-hosts
    Install location C:\Users\Domas/.drush/drush-vagrant already exists. Do you want to overwr
    ite it? (y/n): y
    Project drush-vagrant (7.x-2.0-beta6) downloaded to                              [success]
    C:\Users\Domas/.drush/drush-vagrant.
    Project drush-vagrant contains 0 modules: .
    Install location C:\Users\Domas/.drush/drush-hosts already exists. Do you want to overwrit
    e it? (y/n): y
    Project drush-hosts (7.x-1.1) downloaded to C:\Users\Domas/.drush/drush-hosts.   [success]

    Project drush-hosts contains 0 modules: .
```

I don't know if "contains 0 modules" is significant. I attempt installing aegir-up:

```
    C:\Users\Domas>drush dl aegir-up
    Install location C:\Users\Domas/.drush/aegir-up already exists. Do you want to overwrite i
    t? (y/n): y
    Project aegir-up (7.x-2.0-alpha1) downloaded to C:\Users\Domas/.drush/aegir-up.  [success]

    Project aegir-up contains 0 modules: .
```

Lastly, I run vagrant-build to get a vagrant project going (I presume), this is where it fails:

```
    C:\Users\Domas>drush vagrant-build --blueprint=aegir
    The name of your project may be used in URLs, and so should only contain lower-case letter
    s and numbers.
    It may also contain hyphens (-) and dots (.), so long as they do not come at the beginning
     or end of the name.
    What would you like to call your project?: test
    Would you like to generate entries in /etc/hosts for the VMs in your project? (y/n): y
    You are about to:
      * Create a new project called "test" at "C:\Users\Domas/vagrant/projects/test".
      * Add entries for the FQDNs of the VMs to /etc/hosts. (You will be prompted for your sud
    o password.)
      * Generate Drush aliases for the project and VMs.
      * Launch the project VMs immediately.
      * Build the project using the "aegir" blueprint from the "aegirup" extension.
    Do you want to proceed with initializing the project? (y/n): y
    Copied the "aegir" blueprint directory to C:\Users\Domas/vagrant/projects/test.       [ok]

    'egrep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    symlink(): Cannot create symlink, error code(1314) vagrant.blueprints.inc:90     [warning]

    Errors occurred when running "symlink()" in                                        [error]

    "vagrant_default_build_project_setup".
    Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                 [error]
```

At first I thought, that simply Egrep was missing, I downloaded [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), added it to PATH and checked that Egrep runs from the command prompt, which it did. However, after redoing the aegir-up setup steps I still got the same errors.

I am not particularly familiar with any of these tools. I have VirtualBox, Vagrant, Drush and NFS server, Ruby, gem installed. Running on Win8. I have been searching for an answer the whole day. Could someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to run these commands through an elevated shell (as in, right click on Command Prompt -> Run as Administrator). `Cannot create symlink, error code(1314)` was what I should have concentrated on. The commands ran. Other problems came up, namely – Windows path wasn't getting escaped properly; however, that is off question.

Edit: At the moment of posting this problem Aegir-up was not supported on Windows, simple enough. That's why I was having a multitude of problems trying to run it on them.